# How do I set the port of a meteor-velocity mirror?

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-velocity

Velocity creates a mirror on a random port between 30000 and 40000

is there a way to set what port that mirror listens on?

I am running meteor on different machine, and meteor is assuming that it should connect to http://localhost:35723 is there a way to set the host of the mirror that it should connect to?

For example, http://dev-machine:4000

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only answer right now is to fork Chimp and hard-code the port number: https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-can-i-enable-login-to-velocity-mirror-apps-that-have-varying-port-numbers-for-an-app-that-uses-oauth-login-with-a-fixed-redirect-uri/7185/2

There is an issue filed to fix this: https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/issues/90